How to Prevent Brief Navigation to the Previous Page Before Redirecting with Expo Router?
I’m using Expo Router in my React Native app, and I'm trying to redirect the user to a different page when they press the back button under certain conditions. Here’s the code I'm using:
useEffect(() => {
  if (fromPage === 'SelectLanguage') {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      router.push('/recommended');
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }
}, []);

The code successfully redirects the user to the /recommended page when the back button is pressed. However, I notice that the app briefly navigates to the previous page before it redirects to the /recommended page. This creates a flickering effect where the previous page is partially visible for a moment before the desired redirection happens.
And getting this error;
The screen 'ViewTale' was removed natively but didn't get removed from JS state. This can happen if the action was prevented in a 'beforeRemove' listener, which is not fully supported in native-stack.
Consider using a 'usePreventRemove' hook with 'headerBackButtonMenuEnabled: false' to prevent users from natively going back multiple screens.
How can I prevent this brief navigation to the previous page and directly navigate to the /recommended page without showing the previous page at all?
Environment:
"expo-router": "~3.5.18"
Video Link

How about using a custom back button that calls goBack unless you pass it some prop?
